# Error during attachment ByteBuddyAgent while Mocking java static method using Mockk

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, byte-buddy, mockk

I am working on a gradle project, trying to unit test while mocking a java static method using Mockk. My unit test is simply just trying to mock a static class. Trying to do some research there was some word that it's a ByteBuddyAgent issue, but i'm not sure if the issue is the same and if there's any fix. Thanks in advance.

```
class UtilsTest {
 @Before
    fun setup() {
        mockkStatic(UtilKotlin::class)
    }

    @Test
    fun invFirstReturnsItem() {
        Assert.assertTrue(true)
    }
}
```

And I am getting the error:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at tribot.utils.UtilsTest.setup(UtilsTest.kt:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:118)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:412)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error during attachment using: net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent$AttachmentProvider$Compound@399c2f7f
    at net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent.install(ByteBuddyAgent.java:613)
    at net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent.install(ByteBuddyAgent.java:586)
    at net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent.install(ByteBuddyAgent.java:538)
    at net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent.install(ByteBuddyAgent.java:515)
    at io.mockk.proxy.jvm.JvmMockKAgentFactory.initInstrumentation(JvmMockKAgentFactory.kt:134)
    at io.mockk.proxy.jvm.JvmMockKAgentFactory.init(JvmMockKAgentFactory.kt:34)
    at io.mockk.impl.JvmMockKGateway.<init>(JvmMockKGateway.kt:46)
    at io.mockk.impl.JvmMockKGateway.<clinit>(JvmMockKGateway.kt:172)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at net.bytebuddy.agent.Attacher.install(Attacher.java:106)
    at net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent.install(ByteBuddyAgent.java:608)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: com.sun.tools.attach.AttachNotSupportedException: no providers installed
    at com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine.attach(VirtualMachine.java:55)
    ... 61 more
```

Here is my build.gradle file

```
plugins {
   id 'java'
   id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.3.72'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
    testImplementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    testImplementation "io.mockk:mockk:1.10.0"
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

Comment: It's simple, don't mock static classes. Introduce an interface, implement it with a class, and mock the interface in tests.

Comment: One of the functionality mockkStatic() is made to mock static classes though? So i'm trying to utilize the library's function

Answer (score 0):

The reason is at the bottom of the stack: *com.sun.tools.attach.AttachNotSupportedException: no providers installed*

It seems like you are not using a full JDK to run your tests what is typically the cause for this problem since JREs are shipped without some of the tooling binaries. What Java installation are you using?

Comment: I am using JDK 1.8_261. I thought that might be the case so I re-installed the JDK. I'm also using intellij ultimate as my IDE and actually using Kotlin instead of Java. My System.getProperties("java.home") points to  'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_261\jre'

Comment: Could you try an installation without a whitespace in the path?

Comment: new java home: "C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_261\jre" same errors

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my IDE was a bit corrupted. It also came with it's own pre-packaged version of OpenJDK which i believe is the culprit. I re-installed my IDE and it works fine.